# Does google identity platform supports LinkedIn out of the box like it does for Facebook or Gmail

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-identity-toolkit, google-identity

I am trying to use google identity platform for my application by following the below link
[Google Identity Platfrom](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/how-to-auth-users-app-engine)

But on this page, no identity provider mentioned for LinkedIn and same is not searchable on web.

What I understood is Google's Identity platform is using Firebase underneath. I am just wondering, on Firebase portal it is mentioned that a custom implementation is required for LinkedIn whereas under the GCP account -> Add provider I can see LinkedIn.

What I would like to know is, if it is possible to add LinkedIn as provider out of the box under identity platform. 
[image: GCP account -> Identity platform -> Add provider]

Answer (score 2):

You can use LinkedIn.com provider directly via Identity Platform without using custom authentication. It is the same as using a generic OAuth provider like Microsoft or any other provider. Here is an web example:

```
const provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('linkedin.com');
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // User signed in.
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Error signing in.
  });
```

However, this is currently not yet available in Firebase.